# Find the number of points of discontinuity

Tags: calculus, continuity

**Question** Let $f(x)=[\sin x+\cos x]$ where $x \in \left(0,2\pi\right)$ and $\left[\cdot\right]$  denotes the greatest integer function.The number of points
of discontinuity of $f(x)$ is

$\left(a\right)6$

$\left(b\right)5$

$\left(c\right)4$

$\left(d\right)$3

**My Approach** $f(x)=\left[\sin x + \cos x\right] = \left[\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]$

Comment: What do you know about the discontinuities of the greatest integer function?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг greatest integer functions are discont. at integral values of x

Comment: A little comment about MathJax: the `\left` and `\right` commands aren't necessary for every bracket. They are useful for adjusting the size of the brackets to what's in them. For example, $$(\frac{a}{b})$$ is the result of `(\frac{a}{b})` whereas $$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$ is the result of `\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)`

Comment: Ok, so where does this function attain integral values? There you shall find discontinuities, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг at x= $\pm$$\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: @KislayTripathi If you are correct, then discontinuities must occur at precisely these points. How many of them are there?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг i m wrong 2 is not in the option but now i know how to do it

Comment: Ok, I will answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have written that $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt 2 \sin(x + \frac \pi 4)$.

When does this take integral values? Well, we know that $- \sqrt 2 \leq \sqrt 2 \sin(x + \frac \pi 4) \leq \sqrt 2$, so it can take precisely three integral values, namely $0, \pm 1$. There is a discontinuity whenever it takes one of these values.

We note that it takes the value $1$ at $x=0,2\pi$, but these are outside our interval. Next, if $\sin(x+ \frac \pi 4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, then $x = \frac {\pi}{2}$. If $\sin(x + \frac \pi 4) = 0$, then $x = \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}$, and finally, if $\sin(x+ \frac \pi 4) = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$, then $x = \pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}$. So ,there are five values at which discontinuities exist, and I will confirm this by getting you the graph between the points:

[image]

where you can see that there are five discontinuities at the points of mention.

Comment: Your link is broken. I imagine it pointed to something [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BFloor%5BSin%5Bx%5D%2BCos%5Bx%5D%5D,+%7Bx,0,2*Pi%7D%5D).